# How do I transfer an account between parties on the NEAR platform?

Tags: nearprotocol

From the docs:

> Accounts can be atomically and securely transferred between parties as a native transaction on the network.

I know the currently support Actions on the network are:

```
CreateAccount
DeployContract
FunctionCall
Transfer
Stake
AddKey
DeleteKey
DeleteAccount

source: https://nomicon.io/Runtime/Actions.html
```

I know from NEAR Shell that the `DeleteAccount` action takes an account to be deleted (the "sender") and a beneficiary account (the "receiver").

Is this what is meant by *"atomically and securely transferred between parties"*?  Applying the `DeleteAccount` action?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the secure transfer is the ability to replace access keys.
Let's say you have an account `alice` and you want to transfer this account to me.

1. I give you a public key (without revealing the private key).
2. You create a transaction and sign it with your current private key. The transaction has 2 actions: remove your key, add my public key.

Now `alice` account has my public key, so only I have access to it. And you don't have access to `alice` anymore because it doesn't have your key, and you don't know my private key.